# Is it possible to load all module from a given path in angular?

Tags: angular

I want to create an angular app which load all my bundle from a given path. For example, I have my app and I would like to load module1 & module2 from path "module-list/". And if I remove module2 it will only load module1 in runtime.

I have do some research about lazy loading but it actually load a single module from a given path. And I didn't find how to load multiple module from a given path.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 8, then the loadchildren will take a function which returns the modules.

```
loadchildren = loadChildrenFunc();
```

You can try using promises inside the function to lazy load all the modules you require. It will load all the modules but you should be resolving only one module inside the then function since angular must be expecting a single module.

```
const loadChildren = () => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       Promise.all([
            import('./module1.js'),
            import('./module2.js'),
            import('./module3.js'),
        ])
        .then(([module1, module2, module3]) => {
            ···

         resolve(module1[moduleName])
        });

})
}
```

I think this should work

Comment: I have tried to put promises inside the function but it says me that it cannot find name `resolve`

Comment: Try return that module instead of resolving.

Comment: Not working it says `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Object]'.`